# Log generated select statement from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to debug a query that a stored procedure executes.   There are a number of parameters passed in and a number of case statements in the query so its pretty complicated.
Rather than trying to figure out how to manually construct the select statement.  Is there a way to log the generated SQL prior to its execution.

Was thinking if I could define a string that represented to query then log that string prior to execution, then I could achieve what I want but does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Or I could define a new stored procedure that constructed the SQL and returned it, I could log from my application.  I just don't know how to do either

Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: *how to manually construct the select statement* what do you mean - is this a dynamic SQL query? You haven't shown us any query or context so I'm not sure what you're expecting. If it *is* dsql then just `print` it.

Comment: Thanks Stu - By manually constructing I mean take the stored procedure code and copy it into an editor, figure out what values to replace for the parameters, replace them, then execute that query (in  SQL Server Management), that I've manually constructed based off the select the stored procedure executes... if that makes sense

Comment: Script the procedure - change the create to a declare and comment/remove the AS after the parameters.  Set each parameter that is now in the declare to your expected values and execute the code.